# Usage of "General direction"

Tags: phrase-usage, british-english, direct-speech

I heard this in a Monty Pythons sketch ("*I fart in your general direction*") and I understood its meaning, but I can't quite understand the "General" part of it. Does it mean that it isn't a perfect direction, just a more generic one? Can it be used for giving street directions (*Walk in that general direction*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. "General direction" means that we are talking, not about the EXACT direction, but just vaguely "somewhere over that way". I think the most common uses of the phrase would be, (a) If person A asked person B where some place was, person B might reply, "I'm not sure exactly, but it's somewhere in that general direction" and point. (b) To describe where someone is going when you or the person doing the going doesn't know the exact destination. Like, "Where is Bob going?" "I'm not sure exactly, but when he left here he was heading in the general direction of Chicago." That is, he was sort of pointed toward Chicago, but I can't say for sure if that's where he was going.

Like most or all words that describe approximations, the word itself does not specify just HOW general. If I said, "Chicago is in the same general direction from here as Cedar Rapids", whether that means that the difference is 1 degree of arc or 170 degrees is not specified. You might, of course, give additional words to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a common phrasing. General in this sense is oppose to specific. So if I say "He's in that general direction" and point somewhere. I don't mean he's somewhere exactly along that line, but rather that he's somewhere towards that direction.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of farting in a "general" direction is that if the target moves about they will still be caught by the spreading gas. If OTOH he farted in a jet in a specific direction,  it might miss if the target moved.

Comment: or they can't prove that the fart was intended for them specifically

Comment: This adds needed precision and context to the discussion.  I'm just grateful that this is not a scratch and sniff answer.